# Client named pipe in Powershell not connecting to server in Java

Tags: java, powershell, jna, named-pipes

I implemented a simple bi-directional pipe server in Java using JNA, respectively a client in Powershell.

Basically, I expect the client to connect, send a message to the server and finally get a message back from the server.

The actual results are different though. When I run the server first and then the client, the client waits forever to connect, while the server connects and then waits to read the message from the pipe.

The code in Java for the server, respectively the code in Powershell for the client can be seen below.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

```java
     static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    static String pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\testpipe";
    static HANDLE namedPipe;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        createPipe();
        runServerFile();
    }

    private static void createPipe() {
        namedPipe = INSTANCE.CreateNamedPipe(pipeName,
                WinBase.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX ,        // dwOpenMode
                WinBase.PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | WinBase.PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | WinBase.PIPE_WAIT,// | WinBase.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | WinBase.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE,    // dwPipeMode
                WinBase.PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES ,    // nMaxInstances,
                //WinBase.PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,    // nMaxInstances (255),
                Byte.MAX_VALUE,    // nOutBufferSize,
                Byte.MAX_VALUE,    // nInBufferSize,
                1000,    // nDefaultTimeOut,
                null);    // lpSecurityAttributes

        System.out.println("Created pipe: " + namedPipe.toString() + " invalid_handle = " + WinBase.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.toString());
        System.out.println("Last error: " + Native.getLastError());
    }

    private static void runServerFile() {
        RandomAccessFile npipeClient = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("br1");


            npipeClient = new RandomAccessFile(pipeName, "rws");

            INSTANCE.ConnectNamedPipe(namedPipe,null);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            int rd_count;
            String recv;
            System.out.println("Connected pipe");

            do{
                System.out.println("Before read");

                rd_count = npipeClient.read(buffer);
                if(rd_count<0) break;
                System.out.println("After read");

                recv = new String(buffer,0, rd_count);
                System.out.println("Received" + recv);
            }while(!recv.equalsIgnoreCase("done"));
            System.out.println("Received correct message");

            //npipeClient.write("Hello world!".getBytes());
            npipeClient.writeUTF("Hello back!");
            //npipeClient.getFD().sync();
            //INSTANCE.FlushFileBuffers(new HANDLE(npipeClient.getFD().));
            System.out.println("Sent: Hello back");

            npipeClient.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

```bsh
param ($ComputerName = '.')

$npipeClient = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream($ComputerName, 'testpipe', [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut,
                                                                [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::None, 
                                                                [System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel]::Impersonation)
$pipeReader = $pipeWriter = $null

function WriteToPipeAndLog($msg) {
    $msg
    $pipeWriter.WriteLine($msg)
}

try {
    'Client connecting to sever'
    $npipeClient.Connect()
    'Connected to server'

    $pipeReader = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($npipeClient)
    $pipeWriter.AutoFlush = $true

    Write-Host "Sent: Hello world!"
    $pipeWriter.WriteLine('Hello world!')
    $pipeWriter.WriteLine('How ya doing')
    $pipeWriter.WriteLine('Done')

    while (($line = $read.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
       Write-Host "Received: "  $line
    }

}
finally {
    'Client exiting'
    $npipeClient.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Just a quick aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax in PowerShell: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...`